# Как сохранить и value и text

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть код Автомобиля и его Название. Что мне нужно использовать что бы записать их обоих в форму. ( `textbox.text="Название авто", textbox.value=код-авто`) -В textbox-e такого не нашел.

Comment: TextBox предназначен для отображения текста, а не для хранения каких-либо данных. Но если уж сильно надо, можно воспользоваться свойством Tag которое служит для хранения ссылки на объект. Или если это свойства какого-то класса, то использовать привязку DataBindings. P.S. по правилам оформления, приветствия и благодарности в вопросе не указываются, для перечисления технологий используются теги.

Comment: что должно получиться в результате? TextBox с двумя видимыми значениями для редактирования или TextBox с названием как в Delphi? а так можно долго гадать.

Comment: `Value` у текст-бокса может иметь какой-то смысл если это наследник какого-то базового контрола, и будет иметь тип `object`, и в случае текст-бокса должно хранить то же самое значение, что и свойство `Text`

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать свой компонент, являющийся наследником от TextBox. Например, для класса

```
public class myAuto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Kod { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

вполне подойдет такой наследник:

```
public class myTextBox : TextBox
{
    object _value;

    public object Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; Text = string.Format("{0}", value); }
    }
}
```

Присваивать и брать значение нужно через Value:

```
// после этого текст myTextBox1 будет "Название авто"
myTextBox1.Value = new myAuto(){ Name = "Название авто", Kod = "KOD" }
// получаем экземпляр класса myAuto
myAuto _myAuto = (myAuto)myTextBox1.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

В WinForms почти у любого контрола есть свойство Tag, в которое можно положить невидимые пользователю данные:

```
textBox1.Text = "Название авто";
textBox1.Tag = 42; // код авто
```

а позже - достать их оттуда, приведя к нужному типу:

```
var code = (int)textBox1.Tag;
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно отделить контент от представления. Вашим контентом является класс (назовём его `Car`), содержащий код автомобиля, его название и все прочие нужные данные. Для показа данных вы используете текстбокс (или несколько текстбоксов). Но вы не должны брать данные назад из текстбоксов (только в случае, если пользователь их редактирует), берите данные из контента — класса `Car`.